# Robot Framework is not interact with Snackbar element

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-browser

I am using the Robot Framework along with the Browser library to automate a website that displays success or error messages using Snackbar. Despite this element being visible on the screen and inspectable, the framework seems unable to identify or interact with it during execution. I consistently receive a message stating that the element is not visible and that I should increase the timeout, even though when I run it in headed mode, I can see the element appear and disappear, and the framework continues waiting for it.

Here is the element locator:

```
<simple-snack-bar class="mat-simple-snackbar ng-star-inserted">
  <span class="mat-simple-snack-bar-content">Your third-party has been created</span>
  <!---->
</simple-snack-bar>
```

[Snackbar element visible on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK9UM.png)

And here is my keyword:

```
Validate that the message is displayed
[Arguments]                          ${Message}
Get Text                             ${Lbl_SnackBar}   ==   ${Message}
```

Where:

- ${Message} is Your third-party has been created
- ${Lbl_SnackBar} is css=span[class='mat-simple-snack-bar-content']

Any idea what am I doing wrong?